# Como pintar el fondo de un texto en la consola

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define ARRIBA     72
#define IZQUIERDA  75
#define DERECHA    77
#define ABAJO      80

using namespace std;

int i=4;

void SetColor(int ForgC)
{
    WORD wColor;

    //This handle is needed to get the current background attribute
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    //csbi is used for wAttributes word

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;

    if(GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi))
    {
      //To mask out all but the background attribute, and to add the color
      wColor = (csbi.wAttributes & 0xF0) + (ForgC & 0xF0);
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, wColor);
    }
 return;
}

void gotoxy(int x, int y)  // funcion que posiciona el cursos en la         coordenada (x,y)
{
    HANDLE hCon;
    COORD dwPos;

    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon,dwPos);
}

void seleccionarOpcion(char tecla){

gotoxy(4, i); cout<<" ";

if( tecla == ABAJO && i < 7 ){
    gotoxy(8, 9);
    cout<<"                          ";
    i++;
}
if( tecla == ARRIBA && i > 4){
    gotoxy(8, 9);
    cout<<"                          ";
    i--;
}

if( tecla == 13 ){
    gotoxy(8, 9);
    if( i == 4 ) cout<<"Eligio la primera opcion";
    if( i == 5 ) cout<<"Eligio la segunda opcion";
    if( i == 6 ) cout<<"Eligio la tercera opcion";
    if( i == 7 ) cout<<"Eligio la cuarta opcion";
}


   gotoxy(4, i); cout<<">";
}

void menu(char tecla){
seleccionarOpcion(tecla);

gotoxy(5, 4); cout<<" primera";
gotoxy(5, 5); cout<<" segunda";
gotoxy(5, 6); cout<<" tercera";
gotoxy(5, 7); cout<<" cuarta";
}


int main()
{
    char tecla;
    while(true){

    if( kbhit() )
        tecla = getch();
    else
        tecla = ' ';

    menu(tecla);

    Sleep(40);
}


system("pause>null");

return 0;
}
```

Lo que quiero llegar a hacer es algo mas o menos asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias usar también los codigos de escape ANSI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code (La versión en ingles esta mas completa)

Pero es importante indicar que el soporte puede variar en función al terminal usado.

La secuencia debe empezar por un carácter de escape

> ESC[ … 38;2;;; … m Color de Texto
>
> ESC[ … 48;2;;; … m Color de Fondo

Puedes combinar el color de texto con un fondo e imprimirlos

Por ejemplo, el siguiente codigo imprimirá un texto con fondo amarillo y letras rojas, [image: hello world] el ultimo [0m abierto deja la terminal como estaba.

```
printf("\x1b[0;31;43mhello world\x1b[0m");
```

Donde 31 es el color de texto (Rojo) y  43 el color de fondo (Amarillo)

Te dejo la tabla de equivalencias

### Color de Texto

```
+=========+=======================+===================+
|  ANSI   | Terminfo Equivalencia |    Descripción    |
+=========+=======================+===================+
| [ 3 0 m | setaf 0               |  #0 - Negro       |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| [ 3 1 m | setaf 1               |  #1 - Rojo        |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| [ 3 2 m | setaf 2               |  #2 - Verde       |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| [ 3 3 m | setaf 3               |  #3 - Amarillo    |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| [ 3 4 m | setaf 4               |  #4 - Azul        |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| [ 3 5 m | setaf 5               |  #5 - Magenta     |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| [ 3 6 m | setaf 6               |  #6 - Cyan        |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| [ 3 7 m | setaf 7               |  #7 - Blanco      |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| [ 3 9 m | setaf 9               | Valor por defecto |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

### Color de Fondo

```
+=========+=======================+====================+
|  ANSI   | Terminfo Equivalencia |    Descripción     |
+=========+=======================+====================+
| [ 4 0 m | setab 0               |  #0 - Negro        |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| [ 4 1 m | setab 1               |  #1 - Rojo         |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| [ 4 2 m | setab 2               |  #2 - Verde        |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| [ 4 3 m | setab 3               |  #3 - Amarillo     |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| [ 4 4 m | setab 4               |  #4 - Azul         |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| [ 4 5 m | setab 5               |  #5 - Magenta      |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| [ 4 6 m | setab 6               |  #6 - Cyan         |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| [ 4 7 m | setab 7               |  #7 - Blanco       |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| [ 4 9 m | setaf 9               |  Color por defecto |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes definir el color usando la función system

> system("color *background**foreground*");

Donde background y foreground pueden contener valores entre 0-9 y A-Z

El siguiente código imprime un texto con fondo azul y texto verde

```
system("color A1");
std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::ends;
```

Para ver todas las opciones de colores ejecuta

```
system("color %");
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero lo que busco es solo colorear el fondo de una palabra o un grupo de palabras especificas, la funcion system("color **") colorea todo el fondo de la consola, y no el fondo de una palabra, tal como lo mostré en la imagen anexada en la pregunta.